# Powershell delete row (csv file) based on compare of 2 columns

Tags: powershell, csv, difference

I have 2 csv files neither is sorted:
File1 structure = name,loc,date,url
File2 structure = name,url

I am trying to use powershell to remove any rows from File1 that contain the same name from File2.

What I have is extremely slow based on the number of records I have and how many times this is repeated.
Is there a better way to do this?

```
$file1 = "file1.csv"
$file2 = "file2.csv"

$f1 = import-csv $file1
$f2 = import-csv $file2

$f1names = $f1.name
$f2names = $f2.name

$difference = compare-object -referenceobject $f1names -differenceobject $f2names -passthru

$results = $difference | % {
$f1 | ? { $f1.name -eq $_}
$f2 | ? { $f2.name -eq $_}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this isn't faster:

```
$file1 = "file1.csv"
$file2 = "file2.csv"

$f2Names = import-csv $file2 | select -ExpandProperty Name

Import-Csv $file1 |
Where { $f2Names -notcontains $_.Name }
```